# jquery ui sortable - there is no hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get hold of hovered sortable element `li`

But it simply doesn't fire!

```
$("#sortable li").on("hover", function(){
    alert("yeeiii");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adP6G/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery 1.6 where `.on()` is not available.... also you are using sortable which requires jQuery ui library

Also [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is not an event, it is a method

```
$("#sortable li").hover(function(){
    alert("yeeiii");
});
```

Demo: [jQuery 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DXHSN/1/)

Comment: @SandroDzneladze you are using bgiframe... which is using $.browser which was removed in jQuery 1.9... you need to use jQuery migration plugin

Comment: hah, but why doesn't it work here: http://mac.idev.ge:800/words/ ? I might have created a bad experiment, but on my live site, I've same problem.

Comment: I'm getting the alert when hovering over `drop here to delete`

Comment: I use ajax to load ui sortable elements, How do I bind hover to body, like I do with $(body).on("hover",".class", function(){});?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze if the elements are loaded dynamically then `$(document).on('mouseenter', "#sortable li", function(){
    alert("yeeiii");
});`

Comment: @SandroDzneladze did you try `hover` or `mouseenter`?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze that was the problem... there is no event called `hover` it is a short cut to register `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events